# Match text across multiple rows in R

Tags: r

My  `data.frame(Networks)` contains the following:

```
Location <- c("Farm", "Supermarket", "Farm", "Conference", 
         "Supermarket", "Supermarket")
Instructor <- c("Bob", "Bob", "Louise", "Sally", "Lee", "Jeff")
Operator <- c("Lee", "Lee", "Julie", "Louise", "Bob", "Louise")

Networks <- data.frame(Location, Instructor, Operator, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**MY QUESTION**

I wish to include a new column `Transactions$Count` in a new data.frame `Transactions` that sums the exchanges between each `Instructor` and `Operator` for every `Location`
**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
Location <- c("Farm", "Supermarket", "Farm", "Conference", "Supermarket")
Person1 <- c("Bob", "Louise", "Sally", "Jeff")
Person2 < - c("Lee", "Julie", "Louise", "Louise")
Count < - c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
Transactions <- data.frame(Location, Person1, Person2, Count, 
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

For example, there would be a total of 2 exchanges between Bob and Lee at the Supermarket. It does not matter if one person is a instructor or operator, I am interested in their exchange. In the expected output, the two exchanges between Bob and Lee at the Supermarket are noted. There is one exchange for every other combination at the other locations.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I thought `grepl` may be of use, but I wish to iterate across 1300 rows of this data, so it may be computationally expensive.
Thank you.

Comment: @akrun, I'm guessing it's like table, but where it doesn't matter if it's "Bob and Lee" or "Lee and Bob" that gets counted.

Comment: Expected output now included. Apologies, I should have refined this before asking my question. Thank you for your patience and request for clarity.

Comment: In your expected output, some vectors have different length.  Please do correct it.

Comment: @akrun What vectors in particular are different in length?

Comment: @user2716568  I meant that in the expected output, `Location` have five elements, but `Person1` and `Person2` have only 4 elements.  Itt is a minor problem, though for future readers, it might be helpful to correct that.  Also, have you tried my solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider using "data.table" and use `pmin` and `pmax` in your "by" argument.

Example:

```
Networks <- data.frame(Location, Instructor, Operator, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(data.table)

as.data.table(Networks)[
  , TransCount := .N, 
  by = list(Location, 
            pmin(Instructor, Operator), 
            pmax(Instructor, Operator))][]
#       Location Instructor Operator TransCount
# 1:        Farm        Bob      Lee          1
# 2: Supermarket        Bob      Lee          2
# 3:        Farm     Louise    Julie          1
# 4:  Conference      Sally   Louise          1
# 5: Supermarket        Lee      Bob          2
# 6: Supermarket       Jeff   Louise          1
```

---

Based on your update, it sounds like this might be more appropriate for you:

```
as.data.table(Networks)[
  , c("Person1", "Person2") := list(
    pmin(Instructor, Operator), 
    pmax(Instructor, Operator)), 
  by = 1:nrow(Networks)
][
  , list(TransCount = .N), 
  by = .(Location, Person1, Person2)
]
#       Location Person1 Person2 TransCount
# 1:        Farm     Bob     Lee          1
# 2: Supermarket     Bob     Lee          2
# 3:        Farm   Julie  Louise          1
# 4:  Conference  Louise   Sally          1
# 5: Supermarket    Jeff  Louise          1
```

Comment: For your answer based on my update, the following error is encountered: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."`

Comment: @user2716568, it's an alias for `list` in more recent versions of "data.table". Try replacing it with `list` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
Networks  %>% 
     group_by(Location, Person1=pmin(Instructor,Operator), 
                       Person2= pmax(Instructor,Operator)) %>% 
     summarise(Count=n()) 
#     Location Person1 Person2 Count
#1  Conference  Louise   Sally     1
#2        Farm     Bob     Lee     1
#3        Farm   Julie  Louise     1
#4 Supermarket     Bob     Lee     2
#5 Supermarket    Jeff  Louise     1
```

Or using `base R`

```
 d1 <-cbind(Location=Networks[,1],
      data.frame(setNames(Map(do.call, c('pmin', 'pmax'), 
            list(Networks[-1])), c('Person1', 'Person2'))))

aggregate(cbind(Count=1:nrow(d1))~., d1, FUN=length)
#     Location Person1 Person2 Count
#1        Farm     Bob     Lee     1
#2 Supermarket     Bob     Lee     2
#3 Supermarket    Jeff  Louise     1
#4        Farm   Julie  Louise     1
#5  Conference  Louise   Sally     1
```

#### data

```
Networks <- data.frame(Location, Instructor, Operator, 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```